# Split dataframe, then select random observations from list, and the lists merge back into a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 variables (`subject`, `trialtype`, and `RT`), and I need to select randomly half of the RT observations for the each subject, and then re-create the data frame from that selection.

In browsing the list I've got up to here

```
split_df <- split(bucnidata_rt, 
                  list(bucnidata_rt$Subject, bucnidata_rt$trialtype))
```

(this gives a series of `split_df[1]`, `split_df[2]`, ....)

But then I can not subset using this

```
split_df[1] <- sample(nrow(split_df[1]), 24), ]
```

I think because `sample` only works on data frames and this `split_df[1]` is a list.

To re-merge I would do:

```
remerged_df <- unsplit(split_df[1],
                       list(bucnidata_rt$Subject, bucnidata_rt$trialtype))
```

Could you please help me with step 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a slightly different approach using `dplyr` if you don't mind. You can group by `subject` and then randomly select 50% of observations of each group:

```
library(dplyr)

bucnidata_rt %>%                   
  group_by(Subject) %>%             
  sample_frac(size = 0.5)
```

#### Edit

Here's another way, closer to what you started. I use the `mtcars` dataset in this case:

```
split_df <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)   #split by `cyl`

#randomly select 50% of rows per group, without replacement
split_df <- lapply(split_df, function(x) x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x)), nrow(x)/2, replace=FALSE),])  

#merge the randomly selected list elements back into one data.frame
remerged_df <- do.call(rbind, split_df)

#check the result
nrow(remerged_df)
#[1] 15
```

Edit #2 corrected `dplyr` method after comment by @Gregor

Comment: With `dplyr` version 0.2 you can replace everything after `group_by` with `sample_frac(size = 0.5)`.

Comment: @Gregor you're totally right. Somehow I missed that but edited my question now.