# R: Random sampling an even number of observations from a range of categories

Tags: r, sample, random, quota, categorical-data

I previously took a random sample of postcodes from my dataframe and then realised that I wasn't sampling across all higher level statistical units. I have around 1 million postcodes and 7000 middle output statistical units. I want the sample to have roughly the same number of postcodes from each statistical unit.

How do I randomly sample 35 postcodes from each higher level statistical unit?

I used the following code previously to randomly sample 250,000 postcodes:

```
total.sample <- total[sample(1:nrow(total), 250000,
                           replace=FALSE),]
```

How do I specify a random sample quota of postcodes based on another column variable (e.g. such as the higher level statistical unit (see msoa.rank in the dataframe structure below))?

Database stucture:

```
'data.frame':   1096289 obs. of  25 variables:
$ pcd                : Factor w/ 986055 levels "AL100AB","AL100AD",..: 282268 282258 
$ mbps2              : int  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
$ averagesp          : num  16 7.8 7.8 9.5 9.4 3.2 11.1 19.4 10.5 11.8 ...
$ mediansp           : num  18.2 8 7.8 8.1 8.5 3.2 8.1 18.7 9.7 8.9 ...
$ nga                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ x                  : int  533432 532192 533416 533223 532866 531394 532899 532744 
$ total.dps          : int  11 91 10 7 9 10 3 5 21 12 ...
$ connections.density: num  7.909 0.747 3.1 7.714 1.889 ...
$ urban              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ gross.pay          : num  36607 36607 36607 36607 36607 ...
$ p.tert             : num  98.8 98.8 98.8 98.8 98.8 ...
$ p.kibs             : num  70.3 70.3 70.3 70.3 70.3 ...
$ density            : num  25.5 25.5 25.5 25.5 25.5 25.5 25.5 25.5 25.5 25.5 ...
$ p_m_s              : num  93.5 93.5 93.5 93.5 93.5 ...
$ p_m_l              : num  6.52 6.52 6.52 6.52 6.52 ...
$ p.edu              : num  62.6 62.6 62.6 62.6 62.6 ...
$ p.claim            : num  1.58 1.58 1.58 1.58 1.58 ...
$ p.non.white        : num  21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 ...
$ msoa.rank          : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ oslaua.rank        : int  321 321 321 321 321 321 321 321 321 321 ...
$ nuts2.rank         : int  22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 ...
$ gor.rank           : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ cons               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

pcd = postcode

msoa.rank = the ordinal variable of each middle output statistical unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does every msoa.rank have at least 35 postcodes?  This will be fast with `data.table`

```
#Create a data.table object
require(data.table)
total <- data.table(total)

#Sample by each msoa.rank group (take a sample that is size min(35,total size of msoa grp)
total.sample <- total[ , .SD[sample(1:.N,min(35,.N))], by=msoa.rank]
```

So here is how to example would work using the classic `iris` dataset.

```
iris < data.table(iris)
set.seed(2014)
iris.sample <- iris[ , .SD[sample(1:.N,min(10,.N))], by=Species]
summary(iris.sample$Sepal.Length)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
4.400   5.000   5.850   5.797   6.525   7.200
```

Here is another sample and summary to see the difference

```
iris.sample2 <- iris[ , .SD[sample(1:.N,min(10,.N))], by=Species]
summary(iris.sample2$Sepal.Length)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
4.400   5.100   5.850   5.743   6.275   7.300
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mike. The code works but does this actually take a random sample? I've generated three samples and their summary statistics have all been identical.

Comment: Interesting....It seems to be working for me.  Are you able to mimic the ```iris``` example that I inserted above?

Comment: Hi Mike, on the second attempt this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This <strike>is easy</strike> will hopefully soon be fixed in the `dplyr` (thanks, @Henrik!)

```
library(dplyr)
yourSample <- yourData %>%
    group_by(msoa.rank) %>%
    sample_n(size = 35) # currently buggy
```

Until then, here's a workaround, (thanks to @beginneR)

```
yourSample <- yourData %>%
    group_by(msoa.rank) %>%
    do(sample_n(., size = 35))
```

or stick with plain old `plyr` for the grouping.

```
library(plyr)
yourSample <- ddply(yourData, "msoa.rank", .fun = function(x) {sample_n(x, size = 35)})
```

Comment: There seems to be an [issue using `sample_n` on grouped data](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/405).

Comment: Try `do(sample_n(., 35))` after the `group_by` in the `dplyr` version as a workaround.

Comment: @beginneR Thanks! Guess you got me back pretty quick :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/24461758/903061

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestions. I'm not sure why I haven't got it to work (it's probably due to my inexperience so apologies in advance). Here's what I've written using your suggestion for plain old 'plyr' 'total.sample <- ddply(total, "msoa.rank", .fun = function(x) {sample_n(x, size = 35)})' I don't think I understand the last part properly and couldn't find help for 'sample_n'. E.g.  '{sample_n(x, size = 35)})'

Comment: @ej550 I should have been more clear about where things are coming from. Though I'm using `plyr::ddply`, the `sample_n` is still from `dplyr`, so you'll need both loaded. Alternatively, you could do  `.fun = function(x) {x[sample(1:nrow(x), size = 35), ]}` inside `ddply`.